# Want to replace filter an array in ruby with a defined structure

Tags: arrays, ruby, class

I have a response from a service which looks something like the following hash:

```
h = { "data"=>
  [
    { 
      "alias"=>"abc",
      "code"=>"fgh",
      "code_system_id"=>"1234",
      "diagnosis_code"=>"5678",
      "diagnosis_code_description"=>"Test",
      "last_service_date"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
      "status"=>"PENDING",
      "pastPeriodSupportingData"=>[],
      "currentPeriodSupportingData"=>[
        {
          "conditionId"=>"1212",
          "effectiveDate"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z"
        }
      ],
      "suppressed"=>false
    },
    {
      "alias"=>"abcde",
      "code"=>"klm jh",
      "code_system_id"=>"65656",
      "diagnosis_code"=>"21321",
      "diagnosis_code_description"=>"somesom",
      "last_service_date"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
      "status"=>"PENDING",
      "pastPeriodSupportingData"=>[],
      "currentPeriodSupportingData"=>[
        {
          "conditionId"=>"1234efgh1",
          "effectiveDate"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z"
        }
      ],
      "suppressed"=>false
    }
  ]
}
```

It would be more convenient if this hash had the following form.

```
{
  "data"=>[
    {
      "alias"=>"abc",
      "code"=>"fgh",
      "code_system_id"=>"1234",
      "diagnosis_code"=>"5678",
      "diagnosis_code_description"=>"Test",
      "last_service_date"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
      "status"=>"PENDING"
    },
    {
      "alias"=>"abcde",
      "code"=>"klm jh",
      "code_system_id"=>"65656",
      "diagnosis_code"=>"21321",
      "diagnosis_code_description"=>"somesom",
      "last_service_date"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
      "status"=>"PENDING"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to write a class which defines the structure of the object, so that the array is filtered out the way we want.

Comment: Those are not valid ruby objects. Can you please reformat so that it is not in a single line and post an object that can be copy pasted? Also can you explain in words what you are trying to achieve so that we do not need to deeply interrogate the 2 structures to determine the desired impact

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you probably want the `Hash#slice!` routine, although that is generally only available when using rails/activerecord.

before:

```
h = {"data"=>
  [{"alias"=>"abc",
    "code"=>"fgh",
    "code_system_id"=>"1234",
    "diagnosis_code"=>"5678",
    "diagnosis_code_description"=>"Test",
    "last_service_date"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
    "status"=>"PENDING",
    "pastPeriodSupportingData"=>[],
    "currentPeriodSupportingData"=>
     [{"conditionId"=>"1212", "effectiveDate"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z"}],
    "suppressed"=>false},
   {"alias"=>"abcde",
    "code"=>"klm jh",
    "code_system_id"=>"65656",
    "diagnosis_code"=>"21321",
    "diagnosis_code_description"=>"somesom",
    "last_service_date"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
    "status"=>"PENDING",
    "pastPeriodSupportingData"=>[],
    "currentPeriodSupportingData"=>
     [{"conditionId"=>"1234efgh1",
       "effectiveDate"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z"}],
    "suppressed"=>false}]}
```

during:

```
wanted_keys=[
  "alias",
  "code",
  "code_system_id",
  "diagnosis_code",
  "diagnosis_code_description",
  "last_service_date",
  "status"
]

h["data"].each{ |d| d.slice!(*wanted_keys) }
```

after:

```
 pp h
{"data"=>
  [{"alias"=>"abc",
    "code"=>"fgh",
    "code_system_id"=>"1234",
    "diagnosis_code"=>"5678",
    "diagnosis_code_description"=>"Test",
    "last_service_date"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
    "status"=>"PENDING"},
   {"alias"=>"abcde",
    "code"=>"klm jh",
    "code_system_id"=>"65656",
    "diagnosis_code"=>"21321",
    "diagnosis_code_description"=>"somesom",
    "last_service_date"=>"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
    "status"=>"PENDING"}]}
```